# Doing Ajax calls before Application Bootstrap in Angular2

Tags: ajax, angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I need to call a service (which performs http request) before the application bootstraps using below code:

```
    var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
    CommonService,
    Http
    ]);
    let commonService: CommonService = injector.get(CommonService);

    commonService.getApiDetails().then((result) => {
       platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    });
```

CommonService depends on Http so I am injecting it too as well. But it reports me that all dependencies og Http are not resolved. in Angular2 beta we used **HTTP_PROVIDERS** for this, but in RC6 we use **HttpModule** in **imports** section of @NgModule decorator.

But in this specific scenario I don't have module yet.

What needs to be done to create the injector with working **http functionality**(before bootstrap) in this case ??